# 'Error: Can't assign to function call' while using eval() function in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to run 2 nested loops to separate data from 1 huge dataframe (say, data) into 12 separate dataframes. 'data' has columns (leaf1, leaf2, leaf3, leaf4, .., leaf12). I created 12 different dataframes with names leaf1, leaf2, leaf3 ...,leaf12. I am checking each row of main dataframe. And if that row is not 'NaN', then I am appending that into one of the newly created dataframes using following code:

```
leaf1 = pd.DataFrame()
leaf2 = pd.DataFrame()
.
.
.
leaf12 = pd.DataFrame()

list1 = ['leaf1', 'leaf2',...,'leaf12']
for i in list1:
    temp1 = data[[i]]
    if temp1.isnull().any().any() == False:
        eval(i) = eval(i).append(temp1)
```

In the last line, I need to convert the string in to variable and then append the dataframe into that variable. However, I am getting an error. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better is convert it to `dictionary of DataFrames`:

```
np.random.seed(1997)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan,1,5], size=(10,12)))
df.columns = ['leaf{}'.format(x+1) for x in df.columns]
print (df)
   leaf1  leaf2  leaf3  leaf4  leaf5  leaf6  leaf7  leaf8  leaf9  leaf10  \
0    1.0    1.0    NaN    NaN    5.0    5.0    5.0    5.0    1.0     NaN   
1    1.0    5.0    NaN    1.0    1.0    NaN    1.0    NaN    5.0     1.0   
2    1.0    5.0    5.0    1.0    NaN    1.0    1.0    NaN    5.0     NaN   
3    1.0    5.0    NaN    1.0    1.0    5.0    5.0    1.0    1.0     1.0   
4    NaN    5.0    5.0    5.0    NaN    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0     1.0   
5    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    5.0    5.0    1.0    1.0     1.0   
6    5.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    NaN    1.0    1.0    5.0    5.0     1.0   
7    5.0    1.0    5.0    NaN    NaN    5.0    NaN    1.0    1.0     5.0   
8    5.0    5.0    1.0    NaN    1.0    1.0    5.0    1.0    5.0     1.0   
9    5.0    1.0    5.0    NaN    5.0    NaN    NaN    5.0    1.0     NaN   

   leaf11  leaf12  
0     NaN     1.0  
1     NaN     5.0  
2     1.0     5.0  
3     1.0     1.0  
4     NaN     NaN  
5     5.0     1.0  
6     5.0     NaN  
7     NaN     1.0  
8     NaN     1.0  
9     NaN     5.0  


dfs = {c:df[[c]] if df[c].notnull().all() 
                 else pd.DataFrame(columns=[c]) for c in df.columns }
```

It is same as:

```
dfs = {}
for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].notnull().all():
        dfs[c] = df[[c]] 
    else:
        dfs[c] = pd.DataFrame(columns=[c])
```

And then select by `key`s, here column name:

```
print (dfs['leaf1'])
   leaf1
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    4.0
3    1.0
4    4.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    1.0
8    4.0
9    1.0

print (dfs['leaf3'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [leaf3]
Index: []
```